# Continious delivery to azure for web role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles, continuous-deployment

I need to configure auto deploy to azure for my asp.net mvc progect as web role. I read that i can do this with visual studio online. But have a few questions:

1. How much time take deploying process?
2. Is deploying time chargable?
3. What pitfalls and how good it works?

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I can't tell you how long the process is going to take because it depends on the app you are building, depends if you are going to run tests or not. The deployment process can have several steps like npm install, bower install, grunt/gulp task runner.

2) In Visual Studio Team Services you have:
Free: 240 minutes (shared with Build) 30 minute maximum single job duration

3) I use Visual Studio Team Services in several projects works like a charm!

VS Team Services pricing details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/visual-studio-team-services/